# How can I find whitespace in a String?

Tags: java, string, space

How can I check to see if a String contains a whitespace character, an empty space or " ".  If possible, please provide a Java example.

For example: `String = "test word";`

Comment: What is "empty space"? Is it ""?

Comment: @Dominic - its what you get when you empty a "full space".  Duh!!!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For checking if a string *contains whitespace* use a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and call its find method.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found = matcher.find();
```

If you want to check if it *only consists of whitespace* then you can use [`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
boolean isWhitespace = s.matches("^\\s*$");
```

Comment: Does empty string contain whitespace? bool should be boolean I think.

Answer (score 33):

Check whether a String contains at least one white space character:

```
public static boolean containsWhiteSpace(final String testCode){
    if(testCode != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < testCode.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isWhitespace(testCode.charAt(i))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Character.isWhitespace(char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)

---

Using the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, it's much simpler:

```
return CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.matchesAnyOf(testCode);
```

[`CharMatcher.WHITESPACE`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#WHITESPACE) is also a lot more thorough when it comes to Unicode support.

Comment: I guess this code is not fully unicode aware, because: `This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the isWhitespace(int) method.`

Comment: True, but I wonder how many new white space characters are defined in Unicode ranges beyond `0xffff` ...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, I mentioned it only for completeness.

Comment: using `Character.isWhitespace(testCode.charAt(i)) || Character.isSpaceChar(testCode.charAt(i))` instead.

Answer (score 25):

This will  tell if you there is *any* whitespaces:

Either by looping:

```
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

or

```
s.matches(".*\\s+.*")
```

And `StringUtils.isBlank(s)` will tell you if there are *only* whitepsaces.

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer (+1), but the loop variant can be done without creating a new char array (see my answer)

Comment: @seanizer true. +1 to you. for that :)

Comment: note: isWhitespace method does not take no-break space in consideration

Answer (score 12):

Use Apache Commons [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsWhitespace(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
StringUtils.containsWhitespace(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code, was better solution for me.

```
public static boolean containsWhiteSpace(String line){
    boolean space= false; 
    if(line != null){


        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){

            if(line.charAt(i) == ' '){
            space= true;
            }

        }
    }
    return space;
}
```

Comment: the code is not efficient and it's also not unicode aware

Comment: And it only detects spaces, not all whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Regex to determine if there's a whitespace character. `\s`.

More info of regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

Comment: You could improve this answer by giving the Java code that makes use of this regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test word".contains(" "));
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't check for all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**charAt()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) function to find out spaces in string.

```
 public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   String fav="Hi Testing  12 3";
   int counter=0;
   for( int i=0; i<fav.length(); i++ ) {
    if(fav.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
     counter++;
      }
     }
    System.out.println("Number of spaces "+ counter);
    //This will print Number of spaces 4
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Test Word";
            if(str.indexOf(' ') != -1){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: To be clear, add an example in your code like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late with the most updated answer. You can use one of the following solution:

```
public static boolean containsWhiteSpace(final String input) {
        if (isNotEmpty(input)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(i)) || Character.isSpaceChar(input.charAt(i))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

or

```
public static boolean containsWhiteSpace(final String input) {
        return CharMatcher.whitespace().matchesAnyOf(input);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class camelCase {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner user_input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String Line1;
    Line1 = user_input.nextLine();
    int j=1;
    //Now Read each word from the Line and convert it to Camel Case

    String result = "", result1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Line1.length(); i++) {
        String next = Line1.substring(i, i + 1);
        System.out.println(next + "  i Value:" + i + "  j Value:" + j);
        if (i == 0 | j == 1 )
        {
            result += next.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            result += next.toLowerCase();
        }

        if (Character.isWhitespace(Line1.charAt(i)) == true)
        {
            j=1;
        }
        else
        {
            j=0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.

1. to search for whitespaces

> boolean withWhiteSpace = StringUtils.contains("my name", " ");

2. To delete all whitespaces in a string

> StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(null)         = null 
>   StringUtils.deleteWhitespace("")           = "" 
>   StringUtils.deleteWhitespace("abc")        = "abc" 
>   StringUtils.deleteWhitespace("   ab  c  ") = "abc"

Answer (score -1):

I purpose to you a very simple method who use [`String.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
public static boolean containWhitespace(String value) {
    return value.contains(" ");
}
```

A little usage example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(containWhitespace("i love potatoes"));
    System.out.println(containWhitespace("butihatewhitespaces"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: When refering to whitespace we generally mean space, non breakable space, tabs or line return.

This solution only search for space

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "TestCode ";
        if (str.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Noo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you did and why that is the solution. Comment your code!

Comment: There's a lot of whitespace that this code does not find.