# How to split this String?

Tags: android, string, split

I want to split this string

```
String info = "0.542008835 meters height from ground";
```

from this i want to get only two decimals like this  `0.54`.

by using this i am getting that

```
String[] _new = rhs.split("(?<=\\G....)");
```

But i am facing problem here, if string does't contain any decimals like this string

```
String info = "1 meters height from ground";
```

for this string i am getting those characters upto first 4 in the split string like `1 me`. 
i want only numbers to split if it has decimals, How to solve this problem.

Comment: where do you get this string from?

Comment: What are the guarantees of your input? Will the string always begin with a number?

Comment: i am getting that string from db?

Comment: If the **meters height from ground** is consistent, just strip that off.

Comment: Yes my string always starts with number and it will be decimal or perfect number

Comment: Then split it by a space, parse that split as a decimal, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(info.contains("."))
{
       String[] _new = rhs.split("(?<=\\G....)");
}
```

Comment: now i am facing a problem, when that string is like this "406.9881 meters height from ground' i am able to get split like this 406. but i want upto two decimals like this 406.98

Comment: @RajaReddy PolamReddy :ok then try this... `String[] _new = rhs.split(".");` u'll get _new[1] as the value before decimal.. then u can get 1st 2 letters from the string _new[2].. and then append the 2 strings..

Comment: Both are working well, thanks madam. no need to think your answer is not better. both are good.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can check by white space after first value. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067809/how-to-check-space-in-string/) 
If you get the space then get first character only.

For checking if a string contains whitespace use a Matcher and call it's find method.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found = matcher.find();
```

If you want to check if it only consists of whitespace then you can use String.matches:

```
boolean isWhitespace = s.matches("^\\s*$");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to do this as an alternative to Deepzz's method, this will handle the case where there is a '.' in the later part of the String, I've included an example below.  It's not clear from your question is you actually want to remaining part of the String, but you could add a second group to the reg ex to capture this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String test1 = "1.23 foo";
    final String test2 = "1 foo";
    final String test3 = "1.234 foo";
    final String test4 = "1.234 fo.o";
    final String test5 = "1 fo.o";
    getStartingDecimal(test1);
    getStartingDecimal(test2);
    getStartingDecimal(test3);
    getStartingDecimal(test4);
    getStartingDecimal(test5);

}

private static void getStartingDecimal(final String s) {
    System.out.print(s + " : ");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+\\.\\d\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Doesn't start with decimal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number is always the first part of the string:

```
String numStr = rhs.split(" ")[0];
Double num = Double.parseDouble(numStr);
```

After that you can use the String [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to get the desired representation of the number.

Answer (score 1):

This will work when you know the String near the numbers, with int and double numbers as well.

```
    String a ="0.542008835 meters height from ground";
    String b = a.replace(" meters height from ground", "");
    int c = (int) ((Double.parseDouble(b))*100);
    double d = ((double)c/100);
```

Comment: this is string meters height from ground is not common for all values

Comment: But i think that is an auto generated string, ansd you have a few form, but thats is exact. Then try to replace all if you have like 5. Faster than if you check all options, checking the .-s all the time.