# Get numeric soft keypad on beginning in EditText and make it normal alpha keypad after typing space in android

Tags: android

I want to have a soft input keyboard when I click an EditText. I want the keyboard such that it is numeric at beginning, but when user press space, it becomes normal alpha keyboard. I read an answer about this and they say: Use:

```
 yourEditText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);
```

But in some phones, the space button is not present in keyboard. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You mean in some phones in numeric mode space button not present?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in yout edittext in xml:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

**Edited:**

add these in onTextChanged listener editText:

```
if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(key == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)){

   InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  if(m != null){
      m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   } 
}
```

Comment: What is the event here??

Answer (score 0):

use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), when you detect space, change to normal keyboard layout.

```
onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
 String inputText = s.toString();
  // to detect space in String see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4067825/1008278
  if(spaceAvailable)
  {
        changeLayout();
  }

}
```