# how do i check if the edit text view contains 2 white spaces?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-view, textview

Currently my edit text view checks if the searched term contains one space as follows:

```
if(mSearchView.getText().toString().contains(" ")
```

How do I make it such that it makes sure it checks if the searchview contains 2 spaces between 3 search terms for example: "here it is"

Comment: Add a text change listener to your mSearchView then onTextChange you can check for spaces.

Comment: That is an unnecessary effort in this case and may lead to decrearing applications performance. Unless it is really needed to be done in realtime, I would not recommend going that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do that. Use code like this one:

```
if(Pattern.matches("^\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+$", mSearchView.getText().toString()))
```

Also make sure to check if `mSearchView.getText()` is not null - you probably will get a `NullReferenceException` with a blank `EditText` content.

In the end you may want to create a method like this one:

```
public static boolean containsTwoSpaces(Editable text) {
    if (text == null) return false;

    return Pattern.matches("^\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+$", text.toString());
}
```

just for convenience, clearance and making sure you don't bump into a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: it shows me an error on "^\w\s\w\s\w$" Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \
 \ )

Comment: My bad - made a mistake. Updated the Answer

Comment: Forgot about escaping backslashes... Duh... Updated the answer once more and tested it out in NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but currently I am doing as follows: if((searchTerm.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + " " + mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)). How do you suggest I should incorporate the above code into my code

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067809/how-can-i-find-whitespace-space-in-a-string).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
boolean found = matcher.find();
int mms=matcher.groupCount();
```

Comment: I don't want to limit my words, just want to recognize 2 or more spaces between words